# How to both package with msbuild and run tests on TFS 2010 using Continuous Integration

Tags: msbuild, azure, continuous-integration, mstest

I am using TFS2010 and MSBuild to integrate a windows azure cloud solution to the CI.

To create the required 2 files for deployment I added in the "MSBuild Arguments" the /t:Publish

Here is the configuration I use in TFS to build the packages:

[image: TFS Configuration]

Problem is : if I remove all arguments the tests are built correctly but no azure package is built as seen on the build results:

[image: Build with tests]

Tho if I put the parameters the package is there but the test are not run :

[image: Build without tests]

Is there a way to have both ?

Comment: I haven't done this, but take a look at Tom's Blog for Guidance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/12/06/automated-build-and-deployment-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-6.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had discussion about your problem with TFS Team and I was told that as of now with TFS2010 this functionality is not yet fully supported however such functionality is in they radar and could be part of future TFS releases.

Because you are using TFS 2010, here are a few pointers that could help:

- [Building and Deploying Windows Azure Projects using MSBuild and TFS 2010](http://blog.slalom.com/2011/08/19/building-and-deploying-windows-azure-projects-using-msbuild-and-tfs-2010/)
- [How-To: Deploy to Windows Azure from TFS Build using DeployToAzure](http://deploytoazure.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-To%3a%20Deploy%20to%20Windows%20Azure%20from%20TFS%20Build%20using%20DeployToAzure&version=1)

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to resolve this issue in my tfs build (TFS 2013). I am setting my MSBuild Argument target as **/t:Publish;Build**

Basically, during Publish target the unit test project is not being built. The 'Build' target builds the unit test project and my tests are executed. I also noted that the sequence of 'Publish' and **then** 'Build' was important. Setting 'Build' target before 'Publish' raised a few errors for my build.

Comment: Using Team Services in 2016 and the error still persist.  Good to know it was in the aim.  Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exists in TFS 2013.
I work around it by creating a Makefile project in the solution, and add a new 'Makefile' file with content as

```
all:
    msbuild $(SolutionDir)AzureProject\AzureProject.ccproj /p:TargetProfile=Cloud /t:Publish /p:Configuration=$(Configuration) /p:PublishDir=$(OutDir)
```

And set build command line in project property page

```
nmake /E SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir) /E Configuration=$(Configuration) /E OutDir=$(OutDir)
```