# Team Foundation Services not running Unit Tests before publish to Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm using Team Foundations Services and Windows Azure. My solution has a MsUnitTest project with all of my unit tests. What I'm trying to do: When checked in my source codes and before publish to azure, I would like the TFS to run my unit tests.

I've broken a unit to test, to check if it will publish or perform a rollback and unfortunately it's publishing.

In my Build Definition / Process, I use the default `"**\*test*.dll"` value for Test Sources Spec, and I also tried the full path "$/root-folder/mstestproject/nameofassembly.dll" and neither worked.

Ps: the path above ("$/root-folder/mstestproject/nameofassembly.dll") it's just a sample.

What I did wrong?

full test project Assembly name: "Ipe.Tests.dll"

build definition:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sad" x:Class="TfsBuild.Process" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common" xmlns:mtb="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common" xmlns:mtbc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client" xmlns:mtbw="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mtdwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow" xmlns:mtdw="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow" xmlns:mtbwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mtbwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mttbb="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration.BuildActivities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration" xmlns:mtvc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client" xmlns:mtvco="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sad="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:sad1="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TfsBuild;" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="SolutionToBuild" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="ConfigurationsToBuild" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:PlatformConfigurationList)" />
    <x:Property Name="TestSpecs" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:TestSpecList)" />
    <x:Property Name="BuildNumberFormat" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="CleanWorkspace" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:CleanWorkspaceOption)" />
    <x:Property Name="RunCodeAnalysis" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:CodeAnalysisOption)" />
    <x:Property Name="SourceAndSymbolServerSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:SourceAndSymbolServerSettings)" />
    <x:Property Name="AgentSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:AgentSettings)" />
    <x:Property Name="AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="CreateWorkItem" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="MSBuildArguments" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="MSBuildPlatform" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:ToolPlatform)" />
    <x:Property Name="MSBuildMultiProc" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="PerformTestImpactAnalysis" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="CreateLabel" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="DisableTests" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="GetVersion" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="PrivateDropLocation" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="Verbosity" Type="InArgument(mtbw:BuildVerbosity)" />
    <x:Property Name="Metadata" Type="mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadataCollection" />
    <x:Property Name="SupportedReasons" Type="mtbc:BuildReason" />
    <x:Property Name="DeploymentEnvironmentName" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="AllowUntrustedCertificates" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <!-- Additional Cloud Service Overrides -->
    <x:Property Name="AlternatePublishProfile" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="AlternateHostedServiceName" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="AllowUpgrade" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <!-- NOTE: this deliberately a String instead of Enum type so it can easily be set by server code. -->
    <x:Property Name="AlternateDeploymentSlot" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="AlternateStorageAccountName" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="AlternateDeploymentLabel" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="AlternateServiceConfiguration" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <!-- Additional Web Deploy Overrides -->
    <x:Property Name="AlternateWebDeployPublishProfile" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
  </x:Members>
  <this:Process.SolutionToBuild>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.SolutionToBuild>
  <this:Process.ConfigurationsToBuild>[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.PlatformConfigurationList()]</this:Process.ConfigurationsToBuild>
  <this:Process.DisableTests>[False]</this:Process.DisableTests>
  <this:Process.TestSpecs>[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TestSpecList(New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.AgileTestPlatformSpec("**\*test*.dll") With { .FailBuildOnFailure = True } )]</this:Process.TestSpecs>
  <this:Process.BuildNumberFormat>["$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)"]</this:Process.BuildNumberFormat>
  <this:Process.AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems>[True]</this:Process.AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems>
  <this:Process.CreateWorkItem>[True]</this:Process.CreateWorkItem>
  <this:Process.CleanWorkspace>[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CleanWorkspaceOption.All]</this:Process.CleanWorkspace>
  <this:Process.MSBuildArguments>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.MSBuildArguments>
  <this:Process.RunCodeAnalysis>[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CodeAnalysisOption.AsConfigured]</this:Process.RunCodeAnalysis>
  <this:Process.MSBuildMultiProc>[True]</this:Process.MSBuildMultiProc>
  <this:Process.MSBuildPlatform>[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.ToolPlatform.Auto]</this:Process.MSBuildPlatform>
  <this:Process.PerformTestImpactAnalysis>[True]</this:Process.PerformTestImpactAnalysis>
  <this:Process.SourceAndSymbolServerSettings>[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.SourceAndSymbolServerSettings(True, Nothing)]</this:Process.SourceAndSymbolServerSettings>
  <this:Process.CreateLabel>[True]</this:Process.CreateLabel>
  <this:Process.GetVersion>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.GetVersion>
  <this:Process.AgentSettings>[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.AgentSettings() With {.MaxWaitTime = New System.TimeSpan(4, 0, 0), .MaxExecutionTime = New System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), .TagComparison = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TagComparison.MatchExactly }]</this:Process.AgentSettings>
  <this:Process.Verbosity>[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildVerbosity.Normal]</this:Process.Verbosity>
  <this:Process.AllowUntrustedCertificates>[True]</this:Process.AllowUntrustedCertificates>
  <this:Process.AllowUpgrade>[True]</this:Process.AllowUpgrade>
```

Comment: Possibly the Automated Tests -> Test Source -> Fail Build on Test Failure is not set to True?

Comment: @BrendanGreen No, it's true.

Comment: What is the name of the actual unit test assembly?  Looking at the results of the build, does it include details of the tests (e.g. noting that tests were run, the pass rate of the tests, and the results of the tests, which should according to your details contain a failed test)?

Comment: It just says: " No Test Results" and "Impacted Tests
No tests were impacted"

Comment: I'd say that this is an indication that the test sources spec is not matching the unit test assembly name, and is not running the tests.  If you can add the full configuration of the build definition, as well as the name of the assembly that's generated for the test project, it'd help figure out what's going on...

Comment: @BrendanGreen there's a limit of characters, that's why I post only a part of me build definition file. I think I post the right part. Let me know if you need a specific part.

Comment: [Same problem reported to MS via Social Connect Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c69b4343-1c6b-4ac4-a9d6-cd35287e6783/tfs-not-building-unit-test-project-during-ci-builds-skipping-tests?forum=TFService)

Comment: @BartVerkoeijen I'm still with this error.

Comment: It's MSBuild that with a `/target` of `:Publish` won't build the Test project, therefore no DLL's can be found.

Comment: @BartVerkoeijen Can I remove this '/target' from build definition? Just doing that, will be enough?

Comment: I've tried, but that will do a normal build, and not deploy to Azure. As a workaround, first I do a normal build to execute tests, and then :Publish build if the previous tests succeeded. See this [blog post on how to queue another build](http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/).

Comment: For TFS 2013 and VS online hosted build controllers (possibly other versions), there appears to be a workaround.  See this answer on a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25784342/4313829